# in Dockerfile while copying file from target to webapps it gives error

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to copy webapp in Dockerfile

```
COPY  /opt/javawar/target /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.20/webapps/
```

But I got this error

```
error: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder791542850/opt/javawar/target: no such file or directory
```

Comment: How do you create `/opt/javawar/target` folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can not copy from an absolute path, the path should be relative to Dockerfile,

So place the `target` in the directory where you place the Dockerfile.

The directory structure will look like

```
├── Dockerfile
└── target
```

then

```
COPY  target /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.20/webapps/
```

[build-context](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/)